# Find $3$ non-isomorphic groups of order $2012$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

> Find $3$ non-isomorphic groups of order $2012$.

Is the following correct?

First of all, we have the two non-isomorphic abelian groups $\mathbb Z_{2012}$ and $\mathbb Z_{2}\times\mathbb Z_{1006}$.

Then I want to construct a non-abelian group from $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_{503}$. We have $\text{ Aut }(\mathbb Z_{503})\cong\mathbb Z_{503}^\times\cong\mathbb Z_{502}$. Let $a$ be an element of order $2$ in that group (exists because of Cauchy's theorem), then $\varphi:\mathbb Z_4\to\text{ Aut }(\mathbb Z_{503}), \bar 1\mapsto a$ is a non-trivial group homomorphism and thus $\mathbb Z_4\rtimes_\varphi\mathbb Z_{503}$ is non-abelian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it even easier. $2012$ is an even number so there is also the dihedral group $D_{1006}$.

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't my question.

Comment: What you did looks fine. A semidirect product can't be abelian unless it comes from a trivial homomorphism. (which means it is actually a direct product). I just wanted to point on the fact that it is actually very easy to find a non abelian group of even order (if the order is at least $6$) without using semidirect products.

Comment: [Each dihedral group **is** a semidirect product.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product)

Comment: @Shaun, yes, but you don't really need to know about semidirect products to understand these groups. I knew about dihedral groups long time before I learned about semidirect products.